# Unable to find Foundation Header Files on Ubuntu

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu, gnustep

I have a Ubuntu server with Slicehost (now RackSpace) and am trying to get GNUstep installed so that I can compile Objective-c code.

After installing the world via apt-get and going through numerious blogs to try and get my source compiled, it now seems clear to me that I don't have the Foundation.h header files installed and I have no idea where to get these from.

They are present on my Mac, maybe I could simply copied them over to Ubuntu and it'll all be gravy - wishful thinking?

Any help on how to locate and install the Foundation.h files is appreciated.

**In response to Andy's question**

```
~: dpkg -l | grep -i gnustep                                                                                                                                                           
ii  gnustep-back-common               0.12.0-1                    The GNUstep GUI Backend - common files
ii  gnustep-back0.12                  0.12.0-1                    The GNUstep GUI Backend
ii  gnustep-back0.12-art              0.12.0-1                    The GNUstep GUI Backend
ii  gnustep-base-common               1.14.1-2ubuntu1             GNUstep Base library - common files
ii  gnustep-base-runtime              1.14.1-2ubuntu1             GNUstep Base library
ii  gnustep-common                    2.0.2-1                     Common files for the core GNUstep environmen
ii  gnustep-core                      6                           The GNUstep Development Environment -- core
ii  gnustep-devel                     6                           The GNUstep Development Environment -- devel
ii  gnustep-gpbs                      0.12.0-1                    The GNUstep PasteBoard Server
ii  gnustep-gui-common                0.12.0-3ubuntu1             GNUstep GUI Library - common files
ii  gnustep-gui-runtime               0.12.0-3ubuntu1             GNUstep GUI Library - runtime files
ii  gnustep-make                      2.0.2-1                     Basic GNUstep Makefiles
ii  gorm.app                          1.2.2-1                     Visual Interface Builder for GNUstep
ii  libgnustep-base1.14               1.14.1-2ubuntu1             GNUstep Base library
ii  libgnustep-gui0.12                0.12.0-3ubuntu1             GNUstep GUI Library
ii  projectcenter.app                 0.4.3-3ubuntu1              IDE for GNUstep Development
ii  projectmanager.app                0.2-3                       Simple IDE for GNUstep
```

Answer to 2nd question.

```
~: sudo apt-get install libgnustep-base-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

Since you only requested a single operation it is extremely likely that
the package is simply not installable and a bug report against
that package should be filed.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
  libgnustep-base-dev: Depends: libxslt1-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Ubuntu server are you running?

I'm running Ubuntu server 10.04 LTS and found my `Foundation.h` under `/usr/include/GNUstep/Foundation/Foundation.h`, it belongs to the package `libgnustep-base-dev`. Might be different in other versions...

Maybe you could post your output of `dpkg -l | grep -i gnustep` to compare our lists.

```
root@scm ~ # cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS"
root@scm ~ # locate Foundation.h
/usr/include/GNUstep/Foundation/Foundation.h
root@scm ~ # ls -l /usr/include/GNUstep/Foundation/Foundation.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4991 2009-08-31 23:45 /usr/include/GNUstep/Foundation/Foundation.h
root@scm ~ # dpkg -S /usr/include/GNUstep/Foundation/Foundation.h
libgnustep-base-dev: /usr/include/GNUstep/Foundation/Foundation.h
root@scm ~ # dpkg -l | grep -i gnustep
ii  gnustep-back-common             0.16.0-3                     The GNUstep GUI Backend - common files
ii  gnustep-back-doc                0.16.0-3                     The GNUstep GUI Backend documentation
ii  gnustep-back0.16                0.16.0-3                     The GNUstep GUI Backend
ii  gnustep-back0.16-art            0.16.0-3                     The GNUstep GUI Backend
ii  gnustep-base-common             1.19.3-1ubuntu1              GNUstep Base library - common files
ii  gnustep-base-doc                1.19.3-1ubuntu1              Documentation for the GNUstep Base Library
ii  gnustep-base-runtime            1.19.3-1ubuntu1              GNUstep Base library
ii  gnustep-common                  2.2.0-1                      Common files for the core GNUstep environmen
ii  gnustep-core-devel              7.4                          The GNUstep Development Environment -- core 
ii  gnustep-core-doc                7.4                          The GNUstep Development Environment -- core 
ii  gnustep-devel                   7.4                          The GNUstep Development Environment -- devel
ii  gnustep-gpbs                    0.16.0-3                     The GNUstep PasteBoard Server
ii  gnustep-gui-common              0.16.0-2build1               GNUstep GUI Library - common files
ii  gnustep-gui-doc                 0.16.0-2build1               Documentation for the GNUstep GUI Library
ii  gnustep-gui-runtime             0.16.0-2build1               GNUstep GUI Library - runtime files
ii  gnustep-make                    2.2.0-1                      Basic GNUstep Makefiles
ii  gnustep-make-doc                2.2.0-1                      Documentation for GNUstep-make
ii  gorm.app                        1.2.8-1ubuntu0.1             Visual Interface Builder for GNUstep
ii  libgnustep-base-dev             1.19.3-1ubuntu1              GNUstep Base header files and development li
ii  libgnustep-base1.19             1.19.3-1ubuntu1              GNUstep Base library
ii  libgnustep-gui-dev              0.16.0-2build1               GNUstep GUI header files and static librarie
ii  libgnustep-gui0.16              0.16.0-2build1               GNUstep GUI Library
ii  librenaissance0                 0.9.0-2build2                GNUstep GUI Framework - library files
ii  librenaissance0-dev             0.9.0-2build2                GNUstep GUI Framework - development file
ii  projectcenter.app               0.5.0~20080704-1build1       IDE for GNUstep Development
root@scm ~ #
```

Comment: 8.04, hardy - will try what you suggested.

Comment: answer to question posted above.

Comment: According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/hardy/libgnustep-base-dev the package `libgnustep-base-dev` seems to exist in hardy. Could you install it?

Comment: I tried installing the dependant pkgs but hit problems where an additional child dependency could no be found (1.1.22-1ubuntu1.2)

Comment: You could try the --nodeps flag with apt-get. `apt-get --nodeps install libgnustep-base-dev`

Comment: I don't think my apt-get version supports that flag :-s

Comment: Setup a completely new environment using Ubuntu 12 and then installed the package 'gnustep-devel'. Foundation.h was then present where Andy said. Marking correct because this really helped, cheers.

Comment: Glad to hear you could solve your problems. The wrong --nodeps was my fault. You could have tried downloading the .deb and there's a way to install with dpkg which allows you to install a .deb even with unsatisfied dependencies. But a fresh install sounds waaayyyy better than tricking a broken package system...